# How to standardize a column in PySpark without using StandardScaler?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Seems like this should work, but I'm getting errors:

```python
mu =  mean(df[input])
sigma = stddev(df[input])
dft = df.withColumn(output, (df[input]-mu)/sigma)
```

> ```python
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is
> empty, and '`user`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap
> '(((CAST(`sum(response)` AS DOUBLE) - avg(`sum(response)`)) /
> stddev_samp(CAST(`sum(response)` AS DOUBLE))) AS `scaled`)' in
> windowing function(s) or wrap '`user`' in first() (or first_value) if
> you don't care which value you get.;;\nAggregate [user#0,
> sum(response)#26L, ((cast(sum(response)#26L as double) -
> avg(sum(response)#26L)) / stddev_samp(cast(sum(response)#26L as
> double))) AS scaled#46]\n+- AnalysisBarrier\n      +- Aggregate
> [user#0], [user#0, sum(cast(response#3 as bigint)) AS
> sum(response)#26L]\n         +- Filter item_id#1 IN
> (129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138)\n            +-
> Relation[user#0,item_id#1,response_value#2,response#3,trait#4,response_timestamp#5] 
> csv\n"
> ```

I'm not sure what's going on with this error message.

Comment: That works only for vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Using `collect()` is not a good solution in general and you will see that this will not scale as your data grows.

If you don't want to use `StandardScaler`, a better way is to use a `Window` to compute the mean and standard deviation.

Borrowing the same example from [StandardScaler in Spark not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753088/standardscaler-in-spark-not-working-as-expected/51755387#51755387):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, mean, stddev
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    np.array(range(1,10,1)).reshape(3,3).tolist(),
    ["int1", "int2", "int3"]
)
df.show()
#+----+----+----+
#|int1|int2|int3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   1|   2|   3|
#|   4|   5|   6|
#|   7|   8|   9|
#+----+----+----+
```

Suppose you wanted to standardize the column `int2`:

```python
input_col = "int2"
output_col = "int2_scaled"

w = Window.partitionBy()

mu = mean(input_col).over(w)
sigma = stddev(input_col).over(w)

df.withColumn(output_col, (col(input_col) - mu)/(sigma)).show()
#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|int1|int2|int3|int2_scaled|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|   1|   2|   3|       -1.0|
#|   7|   8|   9|        1.0|
#|   4|   5|   6|        0.0|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
```

If you wanted to use the population standard deviation as in the other example, replace `pyspark.sql.functions.stddev` with `pyspark.sql.functions.stddev_pop()`.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I was able to find code that works:

```python
summary =  df.select([mean(input).alias('mu'), stddev(input).alias('sigma')])\
    .collect().pop()
dft = df.withColumn(output, (df[input]-summary.mu)/summary.sigma)
```

Comment: @pault Feel free to contribute an answer you think is better.